# cx_Oracle not found although installed by Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a box I'm using that, for security reasons, has no internet access.

I've installed Anaconda on the box:

- `python --version # => Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`
- `which python #=> /home/current_user/anaconda3/bin/python`

I've also installed the [`cx_oracle`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle) package along with the [`oracle-instantclient`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/oracle-instantclient) by downloading the appropriate archives and installing the packages. Proof:

```
$ conda install cx_oracle-6.3.1-py36h14c3975_0.tar.bz2
$ conda install oracle-instantclient-11.2.0.4.0-0.tar.bz2
$ conda list | grep oracle
cx_oracle                 6.3.1            py36h14c3975_0    <unknown>
oracle-instantclient      11.2.0.4.0                    0    <unknown>
```

For some reason though, Python can't find the cx_Oracle module, despite being able to find several other modules I've installed.

```
$ python -c "import cx_Oracle"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

$ conda install python-dotenv-0.8.2-py_1.tar.bz2
$ python -c "import dotenv"
# => No problem
```

Comment: Are you sure `python` is pointing to the interpreter from conda? What does `which python` show?

Comment: I'm certain. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Might not be related, but you should never do `conda install /path/to/tarball` since it won't install dependencies.  You should always do `conda install <name-of-package>`

Comment: This isn't possible since I don't have internet access, so I typically lookup dependencies manually and download them. Thankfully, cx_Oracle doesn't have any dependencies from what I can tell: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Please use a recent Instant Client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html

Comment: Made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python -c "import cx_Oracle"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

The cx_oracle is installed in a conda environment. It can either be conda `base` or conda `root` (depending on the version) execute:

```
 $ conda activate
```

you'll see the environment activation

```
(base)  $
```

then try again

```
(base)  $ python -c "import cx_Oracle"
```

You may also use `conda info --envs` to see which environments you have on the computer

Comment: I think you need to instal oracle-intantclient but on the machine, not on conda. Have you try it? 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html

Comment: Yes, but a different error should appear if that library is missing.

Comment: @fny may I ask what new error appears and why you rather have this error?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old, but for anyone coming across this now who's using PyCharm, my issue actually turned out to be a problem with Pycharm, not with my conda installation. Running 'conda list | grep oracle' should show if it's installed in your environment or not:

```
(stats-gatherer) λ conda list | grep oracle
cx_oracle                 7.1.3            py36h2fa13f4_0    /
```

For me, Pycharm was able to find cx_Oracle after a restart by selecting File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.